# Vite build generates different css module classes

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vite, css-modules

is it possible to configure the CSS module class name in the generated index.js file during the Vite build process?

I'm working with multiple themes and a single-entry JS file. Currently, this is what I have when I attempt to build the project:

```
Index.js
<h1 class="primary_AsDf123">Hello World</h1>

Theme 1 
.primary_AsDf123 {
 color: red;
}

---

Theme 2 
.primary_ZxCv456 {
 color: blue;
}
```

The issue arises when I switch to Theme 2, as the generated class for the  element is different from the Theme 2 class, causing the styles not to take effect.

I'm hoping to achieve something like this, allowing me to switch between multiple themes:

```
Index.js
<h1 class="primary_AsDf123">Hello World</h1>

Theme 1 

.primary_AsDf123 {
 color: red;
}

---

Theme 2 

.primary_AsDf123 {
 color: blue;
}
```

This would enable seamless theme switching while maintaining consistent class names across themes. Is there a way to achieve this configuration during the Vite build process?

I am looking for a way to fix it using the [css.modules](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-modules) in the shared options but no look when I build it.

Answer (score 0):

If you built your themes as a library, make sure to also set in the `vite.config.ts` under the `css` property the following:

```
 css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
       ...
      `,
      },
    },
    modules: {
      generateScopedName: "[local]__[hash:base64:5]",
    },
  },
```